# Angular Typeahead dynamically added results

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

I have having difficulties getting the uib-typeahead to work as I need it to.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/0wp1t0ut/ - if you type "g" into the input box, "germany" correctly gets added to the source array, but the typeahead view does not get updated until the next keypress. I.e. Germany is there, but I can't select it until I press the "e".

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is a typeahead that will dynamically update as new results come in (rather than having to wait for all my calls to complete before I return the array to the typeahead).

[Note in my real code, the ng-change on the typeahead is a function that makes multiple calls to different sources, and I want the typeahead to show with data as soon as the first call returns data, and add to that as later calls return more results.]

Has anyone come across this problem before, or able to offer any suggestions (happy to use a different typeahead if a better alternative already exists!)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
  <label>TypeAhead:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="selected" ng-change="vm.add()" uib-typeahead="state as state.descrizione for state in vm.states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" typeahead-model-change class="form-control"  >

  <label>Model</label>
  <pre>{{vm.states|json}}</pre>

  <label>Modify Model Description:</label>
  <input ng-model="selected.descrizione" class="form-control">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', [function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.add = function(){
  var a = {
    codice: 'at',
    descrizione: 'germany'};
   vm.states.push(a)
  }

  vm.states = [{
    codice: 'it',
    descrizione: 'italia'
  }, {
    codice: 'fr',
    descrizione: 'francia'
  }];

}]);

myApp.directive('typeaheadModelChange', function() {
  return {
    require: ['ngModel', 'typeaheadModelChange'],
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$transclude', 'uibTypeaheadParser', function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude, uibTypeaheadParser) {

      var watchers = [];

      var parserResult = uibTypeaheadParser.parse($attrs.uibTypeahead);

      var removeWatchers = function() {
        angular.forEach(watchers, function(value, key) {
          value();
        });
        watchers.length = 0;
      }

      var addWatchers = function(modelCtrl) {
        watchers.push($scope.$watch('selected', function(newValue, oldValue) {
          if (oldValue === newValue)
            return;
          if (newValue) {
            var locals = [];
            locals[parserResult.itemName] = newValue;
            $element.val(parserResult.viewMapper($scope, locals));
          }
        }, true));
      }

      this.init = function(modelCtrl) {
        modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
          removeWatchers();
          addWatchers(modelCtrl);
          return modelValue;
        });
      };

    }],
    link: function(originalScope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
      ctrls[1].init(ctrls[0]);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Facing same issue, did you manage to solve it?